# C# regular expression filter bad word with dot

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to remove a dot in a bad word with regex in csharp?

With a dot you can bypass the filter example: **co.okies**

Text:
**Co.okies are tasty.**

should like
**Cookies are tasty.**

Comment: So... they cracked your system. What about spaces between the letters? Two spaces? Digits? [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: What have you got against cookies?

Comment: This is an example I don't want to write sh.it here ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's partly possible, you could copy your text and remove every character that's not within the a-z0-9 range except for spaces. Then you could match every word in that range against your dictionary. This however wouldn't solve the space issue. The space issue could partially be resolved by making a permutation list of every possible word at with all the words before and after at every word position in the text. And then match those permutations against your dictionary again. Once it's matched you can figure out where you have to start removing and where you have to stop removing. (Don't forget the tokens you've removed in the first step...)

But to be clearly honest, the link Kobi gave you in the comments perfectly explains why you shouldn't attempt to do this, unless we are talking about a very small scenario with finite possibilities. Anyway whatever security you try to implement it will always be hacked in the end.

[Kobi's link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)